# Author of a file using c#

Tags: c#, author

i want to get the author of a file 
i used this but it's return the pc\user (khawla-pc\khawla) which is not the real author (Ines). can someone help me?

```
 string path="D:/testUsers/Auteurs connus/ff_ines.docx";
        string user = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(path).GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(user);
```

Comment: I see your file is a .docx file. By author, do you mean the author property in Word?

Answer (score 4):

To get the author of a word (2007+) document, you can use the [OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) library and access the [PackageProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms571919) of the document.

```
public string GetAuthor(string documentPath)
{
    using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentPath, false))
    {
        return document.PackageProperties.Creator;
    }
}
```

Comment: i need a function that give me the author of all type of file that can be found in windows (word, pdf, txt , rtf ......)

Comment: That being the case, the method you outlined in your question would be the correct way. Are you saying you want the _original_ owner/author, rather than the _current_ one?

Comment: yes that's what i want , the original author not the owner

Comment: I'm not sure the original owner information is available, I'm afraid. Happy to be told different if anyone knows better though!